# multiple lines from textarea to single line string

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i need help
i have textarea which user can put comments on it
if user create new line on that textarea, how can i save it as single line on mysql

e.g :

```
user input : abc
             123
             jklmn
```

i wanna save it in mysql as :

```
abc<br/>123<br/>jklmn
```

here code i use :

```
nl2br(stripslashes($_POST[comments']));
```

as for now it just save in db as

```
abc<br/>
123<br/>
jklmn
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this, store data as it is in mysql do not change anything only while showing the information show it under textarea it will display same. Further you can change the textarea css to look like td or as per your page background. One more advantage of showing data this way is that it will be user friendly to scroll if huge data.

Comment: for showing on php page, no problem with it but when wanna create word xml report, it has extra space infront of this string

Comment: You can replace those spaces,enter character if any in your mysql query itself with use of replace function also you can trim tailing spaced in your values in mysql query itself as per your requirement. I think this can be handled at database level itself.